# Counting number of cases available from datetime in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe of start date and closed date of cases. I want to do a count of how many cases are available at the start of each case.

```
caseNo  startDate   closedDate   
1       2019-01-01  2019-01-03   
2       2019-01-02  2019-01-10   
3       2019-01-03  2019-01-04   
4       2019-01-05  2019-01-10   
5       2019-01-06  2019-01-10   
6       2019-01-07  2019-01-12   
7       2019-01-11  2019-01-15
```

Output will be:

```
caseNo  startDate   closedDate   numCases
1       2019-01-01  2019-01-03   0
2       2019-01-02  2019-01-10   1
3       2019-01-03  2019-01-04   1
4       2019-01-05  2019-01-10   1
5       2019-01-06  2019-01-10   2
6       2019-01-07  2019-01-12   3
7       2019-01-11  2019-01-15   1
```

For example, for case 6, cases 2,4,5 still have not been closed. So there are 3 cases outstanding.
Also, the dates are actually datetimes rather than just date. I have only included the date here for brevity.

Comment: Performance is important?

Comment: Yes, if possible

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
res = []
temp = pd.to_datetime(df['closedDate'])
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    temp_res = np.sum(row['startDate']<temp.iloc[:i])
    print(temp_res)
    res.append(temp_res)
```

output:

[image]

Then you can add the result as a df column:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution in numba should increase performance (best test in real data):

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def nb_func(x, y):
    res = np.empty(x.size, dtype=np.int64)
    for i in range(x.size):
        res[i] = np.sum(x[:i] > y[i])
    return res

df['case'] = nb_func(df['closedDate'].to_numpy(), df['startDate'].to_numpy())
print (df)
   caseNo  startDate closedDate  case
0       1 2019-01-01 2019-01-03     0
1       2 2019-01-02 2019-01-10     1
2       3 2019-01-03 2019-01-04     1
3       4 2019-01-05 2019-01-10     1
4       5 2019-01-06 2019-01-10     2
5       6 2019-01-07 2019-01-12     3
6       7 2019-01-11 2019-01-15     1
```